# Linq Sort a Datatable by DateTime Field

Tags: linq

How would I sort a DataTable using Linq? I've tried the following but received the error: 
InvalidCastException was unahndled by user code. Specified cast is not allowed.

```
var query = from c in allFiles.AsEnumerable() orderby c.Field<DateTime>(1) 
descending select c;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table was dynamically generated and had no actual specified column dataType. When I created the column and specified the dataType the issue was resolved.

I'm not sure why I didn't realize the dataType wasn't defined until after I posted this question.

Answer (score 1):

That would suggest that for at least some row, field 1 isn't a `DateTime`. If it may be null, you might want to try `DateTime?` instead. Or check that it really is that field in the first place... maybe use a name instead of a number?